# jQuery UI Slider: no pre-selection desired

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

When implementing jQuery UI Slider (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) there is always a pre-selection (default value 0).

How can we remove the pre-selection? The slider (button) shall only appear once the user clicked somewhere on the visual analogue scale.

Help much appreciated!

Best,
Lionel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Vd5YY/)**?

jQuery:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $('a.ui-slider-handle').show();
    }
});
$('a.ui-slider-handle').hide();​
```